# Struts dispatcher cannot be found

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

ERROR comes like :

**The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag.**

MY struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 

    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>Struts2 Login</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
 <struts>
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/ServletToExcludeFromStruts*"    />
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="hello" class="com.struts.action.HelloWorldAction"
        method="execute">
        <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
    </action>
    </package>
 </struts>
```

and required jar file...[correct me if i am wrong]

```
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
freemarker-2.3.8.jar
ognl-2.6.11.jar
struts2-core-2.0.11.jar
xwork-2.0.4.jar
commons-collections-3.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
javassist-3.0.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

Your web.xml and struts.xml are fine.

The JARs versions are a little different from [the required dependencies for Struts 2.0](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/dependencies.html):

`xwork` should be 2.0.**7**, `commons-io` should be 1.**0**, and so on.

Btw, since it seems you are starting today with a new Struts2 project, I **STRONGLY** suggest you to start with the latest Struts2 libraries for *at least* the following reasons:

1. There is absolutely not a single reason to use a 6 years old library; if your company has this rule, then fight with your bosses to change this rule, especially for the following arguments;
2. Struts2 versions before `2.3.15.3` are affected by a [serious security bug](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-018.html);
3. Struts2 has evolved significantly in terms of power, efficiency, speed, bugfixing, and has deprecated several old and buggy libraries, like Struts2-Dojo and the aforementioned FilterDispatcher (since Struts `2.1.3`, you must use the new filter, that is the [StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/ng/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.html), as written in the [FilterDispatcher documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/FilterDispatcher.html))
4. With new Struts2 versions, you can use the new plugins out there, that will add real values to your webapp, especially:

   - [Struts2 Convention Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/convention-plugin.html)
   - [Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) (take a look at the [showcase](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/))
   - [Struts2 JSON Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html)

Then start a new project with the latest libraries (currently `2.3.16.1`), preferibly with Maven, or either by hand paying attention to [the required dependencies and their versions](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/dependencies.html).

> [Download a Release of Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi)

Comment: now i changed jar files then exception comes like 
    
**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 

com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/ContainerProvider**

Answer (score 0):

I think so that you have exchanged the content of both files(struts.xml and web.xml) that's why you are getting this error.